# run several jobs in a single file with mr job

Tags: python, csv, jobs, mrjob

I have different jobs in separate py file. These jobs do different operations on the csv file. Can I join all these jobs in cascading mode into one file and save the final output to the csv file?

Comment: Of course you can. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried these basic examples: main: https://pastebin.com/R6UYZdLM

job: https://pastebin.com/vVs9P4tW